# How do I get a golden Gargwa Egg?

Tags: monster-hunter-4-ultimate

I got a quest to gather a couple Gargwa eggs. Easy enough, the game properly explained how you get them. Just sneak up on the gargwa and give them a slap on the back. It did not explain how I get the golden egg for the subquest though.

Do I have to search for a Golden Gargwa to get a golden egg? Or how do I get this egg otherwise?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You get one the same way you do a regular Gargwa Egg; sneak up behind a Gargwa, and attack it.  It will lay an egg, and it might be golden.

<strike>If you want a guaranteed chance at one, you can trade a Max Potion for one to the Veggie Elder in both the Ancestral Steppe, or the Everwood.</strike>  Turns out, that's only a one-way trade.  No golden eggs are available from the Veggie Elder.

Source: [Kiranico](http://kiranico.com/en/mh4u/item/gold-gargwa-egg)

Comment: The second part of your answer is incorrect. If you **give** the veggie elder a golden gargwa egg, he will give **you** a max potion, not the other way around. The veggie elder will never give out items marked as "account item". (I don't know why kiranico shows VE trades with two-way arrows since in my experience they're always one-way trades)